# POST API call returns CORS error without https and ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED without

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple Javascript application that should be able to save a json file to the server.

This is my nodejs server:

```
var express =   require("express");
var multer  =   require('multer');
var app         =   express();


var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './data');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
    }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userPhoto');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post('/api/json',function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        console.log(req.body);
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

And this is my JavaScript, where I make the POST call.

```
function project_save_confirmed(input) {
    if ( input.project_name.value !== _onco_settings.project.name ) {
        project_set_name(input.project_name.value);
    }

    // onco project
    var _onco_project = { '_onco_settings': _onco_settings,
        '_onco_img_metadata': _onco_img_metadata,
        '_onco_attributes': _onco_attributes };

    var filename = input.project_name.value + '.json';
    var data_blob = new Blob( [JSON.stringify(_onco_project)],
        {type: 'text/json;charset=utf-8'});

    //save_data_to_local_file(data_blob, filename);
    upload_json_to_server(data_blob, filename);

    user_input_default_cancel_handler();
}

async function upload_json_to_server(data_blob, filename) {
    const response = await fetch('localhost:3000/api/json', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data_blob,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    });
    const myJson = await response.json();
    console.log(myJson);
}
```

As the title says, If I remove the `https://` I get the CORS policy error. If I add it I get `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`. I tried make the API call with Postman and I get a response.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I did what @js__ posted but I still get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`. 
Here is my server:

```
    var express =   require("express");
    var multer  =   require('multer');
    var app         =   express();

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });


    var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, './data');
        },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) {
            callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
        }
    });
    var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('userPhoto');

    app.get('/',function(req,res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });

    app.post('/api/json',function(req,res){
        upload(req,res,function(err) {
            console.log(req.body);
            if(err) {
                return res.end("Error uploading file.");
            }
            res.end("File is uploaded");
        });
    });

    app.listen(3000,function(){
        console.log("Working on port 3000");
    });
```

And this is my API call:

```
    async function upload_json_to_server(data_blob, filename) {
        const response = await fetch('https://localhost:3000/api/json', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data_blob,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        const myJson = await response.json();
        console.log(myJson);
    }
```

Regards

Comment: try with `http://`

Comment: `POST http://localhost:3000/api/json net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: Is this javascript code reside in index.html file? Also is this index.html file coming from node server? if that is the case you can make ajax request to server by simply giving relative path of the url. For your case url  would be '/api/json' not 'localhost:3000/api/json'. See the url of the index.html file

Answer (score 3):

As described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), `A web application makes a cross-origin HTTP request when it requests a resource that has a different origin (domain, protocol, and port) than its own origin` and I believe your issue is also related to that.

Simply using this line of code to set a header on your response will enable **CORS**:

`res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

This code snippet, however, would enable **CORS** for all resources on your server:

`// Following ES5`

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next()});
```

Use it at the top of your `Express` code after `var app = Express();`

Read [this](https://dzone.com/articles/cors-in-node) article to know more about CORS.

Comment: I tried what you said but I get `net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`. I edited my post with what I have

Answer (score 0):

To deal with **CORS** policy.
you need to install `cors` npm module 
That might help you.

```
npm i cors
```

**In node.js server file**

```
const cors = require("cors"); //TO ACCESS LOCALHOST-LOCALHOST CONNECTION

app.use(cors()); //CORS MIDDLEWARE
```

Answer (score 0):

CORS arises when you're making request to a different server than the one you're on. It is caused by your browser, so, you might get the response in postman and not when you try it in your browser.

Here's a small trick to bypass that error, just prepend this `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/` to your URL and you should be fine.

In your case, it would be:

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/localhost:3000/api/json
```